# iOS chrome automatically adds under line to email and phone number and makes it clickable

Tags: html, css, ios, google-chrome

iOS chrome automatically adds underline to the phone number and email and makes it clickable even though it is div and I tried overwriting the style with text-decoration: none!important; but it didn't work.As there is no way to debug iOS chrome, I could not find the root cause.

I tried overwriting the style with text-decoration: none!important; but it didn't work

meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" -> only works on safari

Answer (score 1):

1. You mentioned that `meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"` is only working in Safari. Make sure you are putting `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` at the beginning of your `<head>` tag, if it is misplaced it will not function as expected.
2. Try changing how you are presenting the phone number and email. You can break the phone number using invisible characters: `&#8203;` and you can write the emails @ symbol using: `&#64;`. This might prevent chrome from creating a link.
3. You might be able to bypass the browser's automatic detection by inserting the numbers and email using JS.
4. You could also display the phone number and email using an image.
5. Render the phone number and email as text on a canvas.
6. Use the CSS content property to insert the information

Inserting using JS:

```html
<div id="contact-info"></div>
<script>
  function insertContactInfo() {
    var div = document.getElementById('contact-info');
    var part1 = "123";
    var part2 = "456";
    var part3 = "7890";
    var phoneNumber = part1 + part2 + part3;
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(phoneNumber);
    div.appendChild(textNode);
    var emailUser = "user";
    var emailDomain = "example.com";
    var email = emailUser + "@" + emailDomain;
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" | "));
    var emailNode = document.createTextNode(email);
    div.appendChild(emailNode);
  }
  insertContactInfo();
</script>
```

Canvas:

```html
<canvas id="contactCanvas"></canvas>
<script>
  function drawContactInfo() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('contactCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 300;
    canvas.height = 50;
    ctx.font = '16px Arial';
    ctx.fillText('123-456-7890 | user@example.com', 10, 30);
  }
  drawContactInfo();
</script>
```

CSS:

```html
<div id="contact-info"></div>
<style>
  #contact-info::after {
    content: '123-456-7890 | user@example.com';
  }
</style>
```